# Ubuntu Studio - ALSA - JACK midi port

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-studio, jack, midi

I've installed Ubuntu Studio (22.04 LTS) and was able to make a lot of tasks. Everything works smoothly but some of the applications I'm using are creating ALSA Midi Ports, others JACK Midi Ports and I can't connect them.
Reading the doc, I think A2Jmidid should solve that issue by creating JACK ports for each Midi Ports but it's not the case, even it runs properly.
Any idea how I can solve this?